# Should each company's stock have its own table

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database

I am creating a mobile app that allows people to issue shares for ownership in a company. I am debating the best solution for keeping track of each share ID.

My first idea was that each company could have its own share table. This would keep track of the current shareholders for each share id.

The next idea is to use a table, shares, and pre-populate it with x shares during a raise, as users purchase them, fill in who owns each share. These shares would be connected to a foreign key, company_id.

Giving each company their own share table seems to be the best solution, but it would also have the limitation of potentially resulting in too many tables to manage. Are either of these ideas on the right track for modeling this problem?

Comment: The shares should all be stored in a single table, assuming they are all basically the same thing (just with different attributes).

Comment: *Should each company's stock have its own table?* no